# Trouble setting activeFocus to Item in a QML TabView

Tags: qml, tabview

When the user changes the current tab in my TabView. I would like to set the activeFocus to the top level Item in the current tab, e.g. using forceActiveFocus. However for some weird reason the TabView is setting the activeFocus to the first Button it finds in the Tab, even if that Button has "focus: false" set. 
As shown in the output below. When I use forceActiveFocus to set the focus to the top-level Item. First that Item gets focus, then it immediately loses focus and the Button gains focus instead. If there is no Button in the tab, then it works as expected. I need advice on a work-around for this problem. I would like to know if this is a Bug or whether I'm doing something wrong here?

Below is the program output when the user clicks on the 2nd tab.

```
qml: Item Focus gained: Tab2
qml: Button focus gained: Tab2
qml: Item Focus lost: Tab2
```

Code example follows (tested in Qt 5.4.2):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    TabView {
        id: tabView

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            getTab(currentIndex).forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var tab1 = tabView.addTab("tab1", tabComp);
        tab1.active = true;
        tab1.item.objectName = "Tab1";

        var tab2 = tabView.addTab("tab2", tabComp);
        tab2.active = true;
        tab2.item.objectName = "Tab2";
    }

    Component {
        id: tabComp
        Item {
            focus: true
            onActiveFocusChanged: {
                if(activeFocus)
                    console.log("Item Focus gained: " + objectName);
                else
                    console.log("Item Focus lost: " + objectName);
            }

            Button {
                focus: false
                onActiveFocusChanged: {
                    if(activeFocus)
                        console.log("Button focus gained: " + parent.objectName);
                    else
                        console.log("Button focus lost: " + parent.objectName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a tab is clicked, TabView is setting the activeFocus to the first Item with activeFocusOnTab set. Button has this set to true by default. I solved this by setting activeFocusOnTab to false for the Button. This is a bit inconsistent with usual focus management in QML because I think normally the "focus" property is meant to take precedence over "activeFocusOnTab" for initial focus, but in this case it is ignored.